# Нельзя преобразовать тип real к integer с функцией синуса

Tags: pascal

> Условие задачи: Определить количество тех членов последовательности
> Ak=SIN(K`2+C), K=1,2,….,10, которые удовлетворяют условию 0≤AK≤1/2.

```
   var
      K : array [1..10] of real;
      C : real;
      SUM : integer;
      a : real;
    begin
      for var i := 1 to 10 do
      begin
        read(K[i]);
        read(C);
        a := Sin((power(K[i],2))+C);
        if a >= 0 and a <= 0.5 then
          SUM += 1        
      end;
      writeln(SUM)
    end.
```

Не могу понять откуда берётся этот integer, который я нигде не объявляю. Что не так с этим кодом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка происходит при попытке вычислить выражение if'а `a >= 0 and a <= 0.5`

Порядок действий слева направо:

1. `>=`
2. `and`
3. `<=`

После первого действия получаем результат типа `Boolean`

Дальше идёт попытка вычислить `and` между булевым результатом и `a`.

В pascal оператор `and` имеет два разных действия:

- между двумя `Boolean` - логическое «И»
- между целочисленными типами - побитовое «И».

Так как `a` - не `Boolean`, то идет попытка применить побитовое «И». `Boolean` легко преобразуется в `Integer`, а вот при попытке преобразовать `a` к `Integer` получаем ошибку из заголовка.

Решение - явно задать порядок действий правильной расстановкой скобок: `(a >= 0) and (a <= 0.5)`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто добавить скобки в условии

```
if (a >= 0) and (a <= 0.5) then
```